# is it possible to align the order of i3 bars in i3 window manager?

Tags: i3, window-management, tiling-wm

I am using two i3bars.
I want bar-0 on top of bar-1 both at the bottom position.
is this possible?
if it's not possible in `i3bar` config, any tweaks are appreciated in code or configs like using `sleep` command to load second bar late

```
bar {
        id bar-0
        ...
        ...
}

bar {
        id bar-1
        ...
        ...
}
```

Comment: Does adding `position top` to bar-0's section and `position bottom` to bar-1's section not work?

Comment: ```top``` will add on top of screen. I want it at ```bottom``` but ```above``` of bar-1. let's say order of bars.it's a status bar.if you use i3 window manager you get an idea.  @Mukundan314